# Black Noise in Small Principled BSDF Materials

Tags: noise-reduction

I have been obsessing over an issue I have been facing for the last week. When rendering a set of keycaps (images below), the icons have black noise in them.

I have tried everything I can find in tutorials and have tweaked all of my render settings to try to eliminate the noise. I have no idea what is causing this issue.

I am using an HDRI background as the only light source, but that has worked for me in the past. The biggest change I made was upgrading to Blender 3.6.

Any advice on how to eliminate the black noise would be super appreciated.

Images in question:
[image: Viewport shading of intended render]
[image: Cycles render with black noise]
[image: Close up of cycles render with noise artifacts]
[image: Mesh of object]

Comment: Looks like Z-fighting, this means that you have two faces directly lying in the same place (or very close together) and the render engine cannot figure out which one to render on top. I guess the arrow faces are in the same location as the top face from the key. There should be a very small gap making the arrow lie slightly above the surface, so that the engine knows exactly which faces are visible to the camera and which are not.